# Text-align not working inside of position:fixed div

Tags: css, position, fixed, text-align

I have some poor looking code with mistakes here (especially div's paddings and margins stuff), put it doesn't matter for now
So I made a position:fixed div and put in a text-align, but it doesn't align the text

```
<div style="background-color: black; width: 100%; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; position: fixed; top: 0px; right: 0px;">
    <br><a style="color: white; text-align: left;">Hi, </a>
    <a href="profile.php" style="color: white; text-align: left;">USERNAME</a>
    <a href="settings.php" style="color: white; text-align: right;">settings</a><a style="color: white; text-align: right;">|</a><a href="logout.php" style="color: white; text-align: right;">logout</a>
    <br><a style="color: black;">.</a></div>
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: It works just fine, but you are using it wrong. `text-align` aligns the text within the element, but the `<a>` elmements have no explicit width and grow only to contain the text. Try `float: right` instead if you want to right align only some of the links, or add `text-align: right` to the parent element if all content needs to be right aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `text-align:right` for the div and not for the links.

```
<div style="text-align:right;background-color:black;width:100%;padding-top: 0px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-left: 0px;position: fixed;top: 0px;right: 0px;"><br>
<a style="color:white;text-align: left;">Hi, </a><a href="profile.php" style="color:white;text-align: left;">USERNAME</a>
<a href="settings.php" style="color:white;">settings</a><a style="color:white;">|</a><a href="logout.php" style="color:white;">logout</a>
<br><a style="color:black;">.</a></div><br><br><br>
```

Comment: No, it does not work, because I want one part of div to go left, other one to go right